# Grouping and Creating a list with duplicate keys in Java

Tags: java, list, dictionary, java-8, java-stream

Am trying to convert `List<Integer[]>` to `Map<Integer, List<Integer>>`.

So this `List<Integer[]>` has duplicate keys for an example see below:

```
List<Integer[]> list = Arrays.asList(
    new Integer[] {1, 23},
    new Integer[] {2, 45},
    new Integer[] {3, 25},
    new Integer[] {1, 45},
    new Integer[] {2, 54}
);
```

The requirement is to convert this in to below map where it groups by the 0th index and put all the values under duplicate key again to a sub list. So finally it would be something like this:

```
{1=[23, 45], 2=[45, 54], 3=[25]}
```

I am currently doing this without streams like below. And am not sure how it can be achieved with stream.

```
if (finalMap.containsKey(Integer.valueOf(dataList[0]))){
    List<Integer> currentList = finalMap.get(Integer.valueOf(dataList[0]));
    currentList.add(new Integer(Integer.valueOf(dataList[1])));
    List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<>(currentList);
    finalMap.put(Integer.valueOf(dataList[0]), newList);
} else {
    finalMap.put(
        Integer.valueOf(dataList[0]), 
        new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(Integer.parseInt(dataList[1]))));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using `Collectors.groupingBy` by the first element of the array and use a mapping collector as a downstream to get the further values. Finally, the further downstream `Collectors.toList` wraps the values. Use `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` for better manipulation with the array items.

Now, the solution only depends, whether each `Integer[]` contains **exactly 2 items** or **2+ items**:

---

#### Exactly 2 items in each array

Each `Integer[]` always contain **exactly** two items (ex. `new Integer[] {1, 23}`). Use `Collectors.mapping` to get the `array[1]` (entry's value) result into the `List`.

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = list.stream()
    .map(array -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(array[0], array[1]))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getKey, 
            Collectors.mapping(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```

Actually, the `SimpleEntry` usage can be omitted and the whole stream simplified if you address the arrays directly:

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            array -> array[0],
            Collectors.mapping(array -> array[1], Collectors.toList())));
```

---

#### 2+ items in each array

Each `Integer[]` can contain **two or more** items (ex. `new Integer[] {1, 23, 24}`). Use `Collectors.flatMapping` to get the `array[1]` .. `array[n]` items (entry's value) into the `List`. Remember, you need to split the array first to perform the correct grouping, therefore the first element `array[0]` is the key and `array[1] .. array[n]` are values - that's why flatmapping is required.

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = list.stream()
    .map(array -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(
            array[0], 
            Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 1, array.length)))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getKey,
            Collectors.flatMapping(
                    i -> Arrays.stream(i.getValue()), 
                    Collectors.toList())));
```

Again, the whole stream can be simplified omitting the `SimpleEntry` wrapper:

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            array -> array[0],
            Collectors.flatMapping(
                    array -> Arrays.stream(Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 1, array.length)),
                    Collectors.toList())));
```

Consequently, thanks to geting a subarray which can result in an empty array, this solution also works when there is **at least one element** present in the `Integer[]` array. A result with the array `new Integer[] {3}` in the input would be:

> `{1=[23, 45], 2=[45, 54, 88], 3=[]}`

Answer (score 4):

Here is the solution without using any 3rd party API and using streams.

```
        Integer [] array1 = {1, 23};
        Integer [] array2 = {2, 45};
        Integer [] array3 = {3, 25};
        Integer [] array4 = {1, 45};
        Integer [] array5 = {2, 54};
        List<Integer[]> intlist = Arrays.asList( array1,array2,array3,array4,array5);
        
        Map<Integer, List<Integer>> grouped = intlist.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(arr -> arr[0], 
                         Collectors.mapping(arr -> arr[1], Collectors.toList())));
        
        System.out.println( grouped );
```

Will produce

> {1=[23, 45], 2=[45, 54], 3=[25]}

as required.

Answer (score 3):

With Streams:

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map =
        dataList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> i[0], i -> List.of(i[1]), (a, b) -> {
            List<Integer> merged = new ArrayList<>(a);
            merged.addAll(b);
            return merged;
        }));
```

For readability I would recommend the merge operation to be moved to a separate method. You could also try achieving the same result with `groupingBy` but this is a bit trickier to get right when using arrays.